# How to load an Excel file in Pandas and segregate the entries based on the continuity of dates

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading an Excel file of daily stock prices (high, low, open, and close), along with the corresponding date and volume.
I want to be able to put the continuous dates in groups of 5 for each week.
I need help manipulating the date column.

Comment: you have to first load them into a pandas dataframe, and then go see how you want to manipulate them. Your question is vague and ambigious, I suggest you clarify what you exactly want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries that can load an Excel file, such as the csv library. Here is an example below where a file is loaded and then shows all the values ​​of the name column:

```
import csv

def q_1():
    with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in readCSV:
           print(row['nome'])
q_1()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to load your data into a pandas dataframe, and your data should be indexed with date. Then you can select rows from the dataframe with this syntax:

```
df.loc['yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss', col]
```

This will select col that satisfies the date requirement. Note also that you can do partial string selection on dates. For example:

```
df.loc['yyyy-mm-dd']
OR
df.loc['yyyy-mm']
OR
df.loc['yyyy']
etc
```

In your case you may want to slice so:

```
df.loc['yyyy-mm-dd':'yyyy-mm-dd']
```